# Special French characters in HTML

Tags: utf-8, special-characters

French characters in HTML with utf-8 charset still display incorrectly.  I have a small sample page in ShopAndBind.com/Sample.asp with META HTTP-EQUIV='Content-Type' CONTENT='text/html;charset=utf-8' that still does not display Véhicules Terrestres à Moteur correctly, whether it is in the source or loaded from MySQL data in a database.  It displays fine everywhere else.  I'm using Visual InterDev 6.0 from Visual Studio 2008 for development. NotePad, Kedit works.  The hex in the file is'E0' and 'E9' respectively for é and à.

Comment: How are you serving the data and how are you viewing it? Where does the database come into this and is it needed to recreate your problem? We're missing rather crucial information here.

Answer (score 1):

The page http://shopandbind.com/Sample.asp is served with HTTP headers that do not specify character encoding, the data does not start with BOM, but it contains a `meta` tag that specifies UTF-8 as the character encoding. However, the data contains bytes that are invalid in UTF-8. This explains the failure.

The data is in fact in ISO-8859-1 (or compatible) encoding, as you can see by manually selecting that encoding (often under the name “Western European”) in the View → Encoding menu of your browser. Byes E0 and E9 denote é and à in ISO-8859-1, byt definitely not in UTF-8.

Thus, the minimal fix is to replace UTF-8 by ISO-8859-1 in the `meta` tag. A better fix might be to make the process that produces the HTML file to generate UTF-8 encoded data.